# Каким образом данные нового массива передать в state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть массив comments со списком комментариев, которые пользователи ввели в форму. С помощью filter по клику на кнопку "Удалить" я перебираю этот массив, оставляя элементы не равные ID. Элементы я собираю в новый массив newListItem. Если я правильно понимаю, React при этом не станет отрисовывать новый список, так как старый остался неизменным.

Текущий код здесь: https://codepen.io/iliyasold/pen/oNoZKov

Вопрос такой: каким образом данные нового массива newListItem передать в state?

Я пробовал изменить state, добавив в функцию `removeCommentItem const [items, setItems] = useState([]);` и затем `setItems(newListItem)`, но так ничего не выходит. К тому же, initialstate не пустой получается уже, раз в списке есть элементы. Как это всё записать? Какой тут принцип? Благодарю.

Comment: Проект есть на GitHub'е? Нужен код этого компонента и родительского. На этой неделе сталкивался с очень похожей проблемой. Если кратко, 1) копирование объектов через "=" создаёт не копию, а ссылку на первоначальный объект. (в данном случае на props) 2) функциональные компоненты плохо отслеживают "в глубину", что происходит внутри объекта в state. В итоге имел, изменения state, но без ре-рендера.

Comment: Да, есть, залил сюда: https://github.com/iliyasold/commentsWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const {comments} = props;
```

Из вашего примера видно что comments приходят из props, а props менять нельзя. Значит вам нужно прокидывать новый список коментов выше в родителя и где comments изначально хранятся там уже и менять const [items, setItems] = useState([]) и React перендерит и отобразит уже новые comments.

Comment: Хорошо, а, как именно это сделать? Как это "прокинуть"?

Comment: В свой компонент commentlist передавать функцию saveComment(comments) через props(как же как и removeItem у компонента CommentItem по аналогии) и уже вызывать эту функцию в функции removeCommentItem. 

А там уже что-то типо такого saveComment(commects) { setItems(commects) }, но уже в родителе commentlist это будет происходить.

Comment: А, то есть Вы имеете ввиду, что следует саму функцию, которая удаляет элемент перенести выше, верно?

Comment: Да, можно и так. И новым массив с комментариями сохранять в переменную которая передаются в commentList через props. Но чтобы реакс пересобирёт нужно делать через хуки useState например

Comment: Ок, попробую, спасибо.

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Действительно: нужно было просто перенести функцию удаления в родителя. Потому что иначе изменений не увидеть)